# WL.Client.createChallengeHandler and Java Server Side API not documented in 5.0.6 Information Center

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I was wondering if there is another documentation source than the Information Center. I found that WL.Client.createChallengeHandler is not in there at all. Are there some other "hidden" APIs that are not documented?

Also, the Java Server Side API documentation only contains 3 Interfaces. The JAR Library is much larger but I can not find any documentation for it.

Or is it still in progress and is the documentation being completed right now?

Thanks for any pointers to other documentation sources!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We indeed have open documentation tasks for this specific missing information in the IBM Worklight Information Center.

You can find more information as well as example code in the [IBM Worklight Getting Started page](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/library/)'s [Authentication and security section](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#security) under "[Custom Authenticator and Login Module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/08_04_Custom_Authenticator_and_Login_Module.pdf)".